# Silverlight and clientaccesspolicy.xml

Tags: silverlight, sockets, cross-domain, clientaccesspolicy.xml

I have a silverlight app hosted on "dev.system-engine.com" which creates an tcp connection connecting to "dev.system-engine.com"

the silverlight app and the policy file are on the "dev.system-engine.com" webserver.

"system-engine.com" and "dev.system-engine.com" are separate servers.

I cannot seem to get it to work. I have been struggling with the policyfile.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<access-policy>

  <cross-domain-access>

<policy>

  <allow-from>

    <domain uri="http://dev.system-engine.com:80"/>

  </allow-from>

  <grant-to>

    <domain uri="http://dev.system-engine.com:80"/>
    <socket-resource port="80" protocol="tcp"/>
    <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>

  </grant-to>

</policy>
```

Comment: You say the policy file is on the webserver, but where? It must be in the root of the server.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and resorted to using the `crossdomain.xml` file instead.  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481817/what-are-the-biggest-gotchas-in-silverlight-2-0/481831#481831) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481817/what-are-the-biggest-gotchas-in-silverlight-2-0). I have never managed to get `clientaccesspolicy.xml` to work.