# Is it possible to access a Silverlight XAP file across a two local host domain?

Tags: c#, silverlight, media-player

Hi I had created a silver light application with media player. And it is working in that app fine. When i use the embed code to some other application as meta tag. It fails to load the zap file and video. Can i know how can i fix it.

Here is code:

```
<object height="360" width="640" type="application/x-silverlight-2" data="data:application/x-silverlight,">
<param value="http://localhost:1069/ClientBin/MymediaPlayer.xap" name="source">
<param value="onSilverlightError" name="onerror">
<param value="white" name="background">
<param value="m=http://localhost:1069/content/en-us/videofile/Butterfly.wmv" name="initParams">         
        </object>
```

When i use this in the silver light application it is working. but this meta tag should work on all other domain. I had tested on two local host domain.

Thanks in Advance.

KK

Comment: What do you mean "as meta tag"?  Doesn't make a great deal of sense.  Do you mean when you place this markup in HTML served from another server?

Comment: also for anyone who comes across this undocumented enum... setting ExternalCallersFromCrossDomain in the manifest to FullAccess does not work. http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/56/10050545/silverlight-xap-crossdom.aspx

Comment: i'm also interested in knowing whether this is possible. not necessarily from two local network hosts, but across any two internet hosts. i don't think the OP actually cares about accessing a web service from the xap, but does care sourcing the xap on one server and accessing it from another.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a `clientaccesspolicy.xml` file or a `crossdomain.xml` file in order to permit access to your web services from different domains.

This is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481817/what-are-the-biggest-gotchas-in-silverlight-2-0/481831#481831).