# Firefox plugin for silverlight is getting crashed frequently at the time of debugging

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

When i try to debug silverlight application by attaching plugin process to it...then silverlight application is frequently crashing...please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reading this answer

[How do you debug Silverlight applications with Chrome AND hit breakpoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064647/how-do-you-debug-silverlight-applications-with-chrome-and-hit-breakpoints)

and this page:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/304582/Silverlight-debugging-Beginners-Guide

which may help you figure out what is wrong.